# Segmentation fault while trying to access empty vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector

So I made a 2D array of chars but Every time I try to access it I get a segmentation fault and I cannot figure out why.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix_;

//Filling it with space ' ' characters
std::vector<char> aRow;
matrix_.resize(height_, aRow);
for (std::vector<char> row : matrix_) {
    row.resize(width_, ' ');
}

std::cout << matrix_[0][0]; //Segmentation fault here
```

Comment: `for (std::vector<char> row : ` is making a copy.

Comment: `for (auto&& row : matrix_)` , and save yourself some typing in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `auto&& row : matrix_` (note the reference added), in the `for` to get the reference to each row you are looking for.

As you have it, it creates a copy, resizes it and discards the result.

Without being too pessimistic about it, you could also look to resize each column with the right sized row. The `for` loop is not needed.

```
std::vector<char> aRow(width_, ‘ ‘);
matrix_.resize(height_, aRow);
```

Comment: Ah I see where the error is. thanks!

But why the && instead of & ?

Comment: I'm a begginer so I'd like to avoid auto for now till  I understand types better. But using a single & works! Thanks!

Comment: `std::vector<char> aRow; aRow.resize(width_, ‘ ‘);` can be simplified to `std::vector<char> aRow(width_, ‘ ‘);`